# How to dynamically update updateURL in install.rdf?

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox, xul, xulrunner

Is it possible to dynamically update updateURL into install.rdf file. I have my update url in a javascript file stored in a variable, is it possible to use this url as update url in install.rdf file in xpi ?

Answer (score 0):

You can update your add-ons manifest but you cannot pass your own URL as update URL.

This part is just an **FYI**:

if you look into `omni.ja\modules\XPIProvider.jsm`, function `loadManifest` (line 4601) , you can see that it reads update URL from your add-on's manifest. After loading the manifest, it will use its updateURL to send request and check for an update(`UpdateChecker`).